# How can I deploy Node Js back-end and React Js front-end on server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-deployment, digital-ocean

I have created a back-end using Node Express which is running on `port 5000`. And my front-end using React Js which is running on `port 3000`. And both of them are in different folders in root directory.

I want to upload both of these and deploy on digital ocean Server. I am new to this department process. How can I deploy both of these on server and run by one command, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it (using node server to serve as an API for React website served by Apache server).

You can leave nodejs running on port 5000 (on the remote server) but make sure that you are not using `localhost` but `0.0.0.0`.

ie. `app.listen(5000, "0.0.0.0")`;

Now, you should be able to communicate with the node server via public IP/DNS name on that port ie. *myPublicIpOrDNSname:5000*. (assuming that you have installed `nodejs` as well as `npm` => be careful about version, `apt-get install nodejs`, by default, will fetch an older version)

If you need newer version of `nodejs` then you can fetch it by following these steps (you can replace that `setup_8.x` part with your preferred version).

```
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Use Apache2 server to serve your static (React, css, ...) files (you don't need to run `create-react-app server`).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Build your React project using `npm run build` and then place the files that were created inside of `/build` folder (in the React folder) to `/var/www/html` (on the remote server). Note that you need to place there files and folders from `/build` folder, not the `/build` folder itself.

Now you should be able to see your react website running when you type the *myPublicIpOrDNSname* address (assuming that Apache is running `sudo systemctl start apache2`).

For Apache to work correctly (if you are using front-end routing - ie. `react-router-dom`), you need to go to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and place this configuration

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    RewriteEngine on
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</Directory>
```

under `<VirtualHost ...>` section in that file. (Apache does't know about your React routes. This will make it push every request that it doesn't know how to handle to the root and leave React handle the routing)

Then you need to make sure that RewriteEngine is running (otherwise you will get an error when restarting Apache server).

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Finally, restart Apache server

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Now, it should work.

Note that you need to modify your ajax calls in your React with the new public IP/DNS.

Comment: The server is using `localhost`. How to change it to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: @testteam In the place where you are starting your server (ie. index.js) you have a line `app.listen(5000, ...)` or `server.listen(5000)` or `server.listen(port, ...)` or something similar with the `listen` method. Just add `0.0.0.0` as the second argument to that method (`ie. app.listen(5000, "0.0.0.0")`)

Answer (score 1):

If your front-end is create react app, you can do `npm run build`, and serve static assets in nodejs via nodejs in the same server. It will serve the minified chunks.

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));`

Comment: Currently I used `npm start` for React. Only `npm run build` is enough for both Node and React?

Comment: Did you find it? Can you please help me I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can server side render your react app from your Node.js/Express, I think currently your are using webpack to render your react app on port 3000. If you can upload your code to take a look it will be easier to help

Comment: How to use webpack?

Comment: I think you are already using webpack , it is an assets bundler and also has plugins one of them called dev server where you can serve your react app, easiest thing is to check if you have  webpack.config.js  and if you have webpack npm dependency

Comment: No i didn't use webpack. How to use it?

Comment: So I suggest you use it, especially if you are planning to put this in production, I think it will be another topic with long answer so I will do my best here to help you get started. You will need to install webpack as a dev dependency  and then create webpack.config.js with a config object that match your app like for example
module.exports = {
  mode: "production", // "production" | "development" | "none"  // Chosen mode tells webpack to use its built-in optimizations accordingly.
  entry: "./app/entry", // string | object | array  // defaults to './src'
  // Here the application starts

Comment: here is the more complete config file https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

Comment: So, should I install `webpack` module ?